# Prevent Outlook 2010 from auto-deleting old items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I stop Outlook 2010 from removing anything over 30 days old from my deleted items folder? I have tried going through all of the advanced options, but am unable to find anything to do with how long deleted items stay in the deleted items folder.

Answer (score 4):

In Options select 'Advanced' and scroll to AutoArchive section. Select the 'AutoArchive Settings' button. Change the 'Permanently delete old items' setting.

[image]