# Outlook 2010 deleting old emails - not AutoArchive

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 is deleting my old emails. I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/552246/prevent-outlook-2010-from-auto-deleting-old-items) but the answer there says to check AutoArchive settings. My settings look fine, and they're grayed out anyway:

[image]

So is there another reason Outlook might be deleting my old emails? Scripts or macros maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your rules looking like? Perhaps there's an auto delete rule somewhere.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network? Is your Outlook connected to an exchange server?

Comment: If the options are greyed out, then its probably because (as CharlieRB suggests) you are on a corporate network and your company's admin has applied policies to control your archive settings for you.  IF this is the case (you are on a work, domain-based network), you'll have to check with them.  Aside from that, we can't tell you what scripts and macros you have chosen to implement unfortunately.  So if you suspect scripting, what have your investigations found so far?  Do you actually have scripts/macros programmed into your Outlook?

Comment: Yes, it's on a corporate network. But the options there don't look like they're set up for automatic deletion.

Comment: I don't have any rules that would control this. Just a few that move automatically-generated emails to a particular folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a corporate environment, it will be a Group Policy that is set by the Exchange Email Administrator.

- Right click on youremail@yourcompany.xyz and select Folder Permissions

[image: Folder Permissions]

- Then click on Add or Remove Retention Policies

You might get sent to Outlook for Web where you can set policies.. or nothing appears which means this is disabled by your administrator and is uneditable.

If the Folder Policy is editable, then it might give you the details of the Archive policy. It sounds like your e-mails are set to be deleted after x number of days. You can verify by seeing what is your oldest e-mail in your Sent Items.

[image: Add or Remove Retention Policies]

First check why there is a deletion policy and not retention. If deletion policy is there to save disk space (bad policy), then you could try setting up your own AutoArchive to pre-empty the policy and save your e-mail to a local PST to archives emails before they are deleted.

If Group Policy affects even your local PST, then you'll have to figure out a different way to save your old e-mails.

Comment: "Sorry! Access is denied!" Dang. I was trying to exercise CYA methodology, but I guess they don't want me C'ing my A. Thanks for the help.